# Comparing 2 files in awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

I've 2 Input Files as below.

```
File1

India USA China Russia France England

File2

India
USA
China
Russia
France
England
```

I need to validate whether all the Columns in File 2 is available in File 1 in the same order. What is the efficient way to achieve this in awk scripting(ksh)

I've written a sample script as below. But, I would like to know the simple and efficient solution.

```
#!/bin/ksh
        i=1
while read line
do
        val=`cat File1 | cut -d" " -f$i`
        echo $val $line

        if [ $val = $line ]
        then
                echo "Matches"
        else

                echo "Not matches"
        fi
        i=$((i+1))
done < ./File2
```

Comment: Also please do mention expected output too in your post.

Comment: With ksh or bash: `if diff -Z <(tr ' ' '\n' <file1) file2; then echo "okay"; else echo "not okay"; fi`

Comment: Updated the Question with the sample code and my requirement. Removed the trailing space behind Russia

Comment: @Cyrus I tried as you mentioned but it's giving below Error.                              
        diff: invalid option -- 'Z'

Comment: Remove `-Z`. This option was only for ignoring the space at the end of the lines with GNU diff.

Comment: Too bad ALL of your file2 lines match so there's no way to actually test a script to see if it correctly identifies the matching/unmatching lines or not. It's good to put some thought into covering use cases when providing sample input/output so it's useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following once? Tested with provided samples only.

```
awk '
{
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
}
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$0
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    count=a[i]==$i?++count:count
  }
  if(count==length(a)){
    print "Line number " FNR " whose contents are:" $0 " present in both the files."
  }
  count=""
}'   Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Line number 1 whose contents are:India USA China Russia France England present in both the files.
```

In case your strings may contain capital or small letters mix in their values now adding that solution which could take care of that issue.

```
awk '
{
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
}
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=tolower($0)
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    count=a[i]==tolower($i)?++count:count
  }
  if(count==length(a)){
    print "Line number " FNR " whose contents are:" $0 " present in both the files."
  }
  count=""
}'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Or as discussed in chat code with else condition.

```
awk '
{
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
}
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=tolower($0)
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    count=a[i]==tolower($i)?++count:count
  }
  if(count==length(a)){
    print "Line number " FNR " whose contents are:" $0 " present in both the files."
  }
  else{
    print "Line number " FNR " is NOT matching..."
  }
  count=""
}'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Comment: @Vinoth Karthick, could you please try my solution once if this helps you?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code (changed the Input File Names)in a ksh scirpt and executed the ksh script . It does not give any output. Should I run it in a different way?

Comment: @VinothKarthick, first try running it on server terminal itself as command and make sure you are passing 2file names like I mentioned as follows `Input_file2   Input_file1` too, let me know?

Comment: I tried running in terminal too. It's not giving any output , The File names are correctly given

Comment: @VinothKarthick, ok can you check running `cat -v file1` and `cat -v file2` on both your files and check if there are any carriage returns characters in there? Let me know?

Comment: I checked , No Carriage Returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185753/discussion-between-ravindersingh13-and-vinoth-karthick).

Answer (score 1):

Following awk command will work even if `File1` has multiple lines.

```
awk 'FNR == NR { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) a[++n] = $i; next }
     { print "Line " FNR ": " ($0 == a[FNR] ? "matches" : "does not match.") "." }' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
Line 1: matches.
Line 2: matches.
Line 3: matches.
Line 4: matches.
Line 5: matches.
Line 6: matches.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ paste <(tr ' ' '\n' < file1) file2 | awk '{print $0, ($1 == $2 ? "" : "no ") "match"}'
#India   India match
#USA     USA match
#China   China match
#Russia  Russia match
#France  France match
#England England match
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat vinoth1.txt
India USA China Russia France England

$ cat vinoth2.txt
India
USA
China
Russia
France
England

$ perl -lane ' BEGIN{@k=map{chomp($_);$_} qx(cat vinoth2.txt)} print "Line:$. matches" if join(" ",@k) eq join(" ",@F) ' vinoth1.txt
Line:1 matches
```